# Set all back button titles in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to be clever about setting all `title` properties of the the "Back" buttons in a UINavigationController so that I don't have to do `self.navigationController.navigationBar.backButtonItem.title = "Back"` everywhere or subclass a `UINavigationController` and set it everywhere, so I've created this extension:

```
extension UINavigationItem {
    open var backBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem? {
        get {
            return self.backBarButtonItem
        }

        set {
            newValue?.title = "Back"
            backBarButtonItem = newValue?
        }
    }
}
```

But it says `'backBarButtonItem' used within its own type`.

Has anybody done this before or can think of a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you cannot create a variable with the name which is similar to those variables which are defined in the SDK.

You can't override the existing functionality

Like in your case you are naming it as `backBarButtonTitle` which is defined as `open var backBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem?` in `UINavigationBar` class of `UIKit`

As it is mentioned in [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) of Apple

> Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot
>   override existing functionality.

Comment: That's because I want to try to override the backBarButtonItem that's already there and change the title before setting it - is this not possible in an extension? Only in a subclass?

Comment: @ChrisByatt You can't override existing functionality with extension, updated my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Please follow this Screen shot Image then run your project .  I think you can solved your problem easily :)[image]